# How to set the appropriate number of pools when running multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying run a web-scraper using multiprocessing. I have some issues understanding the appropriate number of pools. Is the norm that I should use the number of pools as `cpu_count()`?

My code is like this:

```
def experiment(df,n):
    with Pool(n) as p:
        results = p.map(ind_scraper_iterator, df)
    return(results)
```

`df` is a list of dictionaries (length is around 3K), and the `ind_scraper_iterator` function uses the fields in the dictionaries to query and scrape from the web. I tried setting `n` to 600 and 700, but I got an error message `BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable`. I gather this is because of the number of the pools, and I want to select the appropriate number so I do not get blocked.

Answer (score 0):

In CPU-bound use-cases, yes, you want the pool size to be no greater than  the number of CPU cores available. If you are doing CPU-bound work in your `Pool`, it is not possible to do more than `cpu_count()` operations in parallel, because there simply aren't any CPUs available to do more. Once you have more processes in your Pool than there are CPUs, you actually end up hurting performance, because the OS has to context switch between the extra processes, so that they all get some CPU time, which adds overhead.

The only time you would want to have more processes in your `Pool` than you have CPU cores is if the work you're doing in the processes is I/O-bound, and spends most of its time blocking, waiting for I/O to complete. Waiting for I/O doesn't use any CPU resources, so you can scale beyond the number of CPU cores available without diminishing returns.

In your use-case, you're doing web-scraping, which does involve I/O (to fetch the data from the web). I don't know enough about the specifics to know if there's enough I/O (when compared to whatever else you're doing after fetching the data) to justify a pool larger than `cpu_count()` or not. You will have to do your own tests to find the sweet spot. I will say that 600-700 processes is likely too many, simply because running a process creates quite a bit of memory overhead, and can overload the system. If your use-case turns out to be heavily I/O-bound, you may want to just use a thread pool instead, since I/O can be parallelized effectively with just Threads. It is only CPU-bound work that does not release the GIL that can't be parallelize in (C)Python. You may find that having a small amount of CPU work get serialized ends up being cheaper than having it run in parallel, but having to deal with the inter-process communication overhead introduced by `multiprocessing`.

As always, you will need to do your own tests to determine what works best for your specific use-case.